# Show that any vector $\vec{d}$ can be expressed as follows

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, cross-product

**Question:** Prove that any vector $\vec{d}$ can be expressed as, $$\vec{d}=\dfrac{\left\{ \vec{a}\cdot\vec{d}(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})\right\}+\left\{ \vec{b}\cdot  \vec{d}(\vec{c}\times \vec{a})\right\}+\left\{ \vec{c}\cdot  \vec{d}(\vec{a}\times \vec{b})\right\}}{[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]}$$

**My effort:** Any three non-co-planar vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ can be expressed as $\vec{d}=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}$. Then
$\vec{d}=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}\implies \vec{d}\cdot(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})=x[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]\implies x=\dfrac{\vec{d}\cdot(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})}{[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]}$. In this way we have
$$\vec{d}=\dfrac{\left\{ \vec{d}\cdot(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})\right\}\vec{a}+\left\{ \vec{d}\cdot(\vec{c}\times \vec{a})\right\}\vec{b}+\left\{ \vec{d}\cdot(\vec{a}\times \vec{b})\right\}\vec{c}}{[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]}$$ which is different from the required result.  What to do now to show the required result?

Comment: By the way, what you did is not exactly wrong. It was just not what the problem asked. Your line of reasoning here will still be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are linearly independent, so are $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$, $\vec{b}\times \vec{c}$ and $\vec{c}\times \vec{a}$. Then write $$\vec{d} = \alpha (\vec{b}\times \vec{c}) +\beta(\vec{c}\times\vec{a})+\gamma(\vec{a}\times \vec{b})$$for some $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$. The goal is to solve for those coefficients. Dotting the above with $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ we obtain $$\vec{d}\cdot \vec{a} = \alpha[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}], \qquad \vec{d}\cdot\vec{b} = \beta[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}] \quad \mbox{and}\quad \vec{d}\cdot \vec{c} = \gamma[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}].$$This means that $$\vec{d} = \frac{\vec{d}\cdot\vec{a}}{[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]}(\vec{b}\times \vec{c}) + \frac{\vec{d}\cdot\vec{b}}{[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]}(\vec{c}\times\vec{a}) + \frac{\vec{d}\cdot\vec{c}}{[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]}(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}),$$as wanted.